# How do I stop the input form to change background color and text color when I input and submit something?

Tags: javascript, css, forms

```
.button{
    outline-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width:290px;
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 5px;
    height:80px;
    font-size:44px;
    color:orange;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border: 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    cursor:pointer;
} 
.button:hover{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    
.button:focus{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        width: 300px;
}



<form action="" onsubmit="return submitMove()">
        <label class="lable">First Coordinate</label>
        <div><input class="button" type="text" id="currentCoordinate" onchange="backgroundColor: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" onclick="clickInput()"></div>
        <lable class="lable">Second Coordinate</lable>
        <div><input class="button" type="text" id="moveToCoordinate"  onchange="backgroundColor: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" onclick="clickInput()"></div>
        <button class="button" onclick="clickInput()">Submit move</button>
    </form>




function clickInput() {
    document.getElementById("currentCoordinate").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
    document.getElementById("moveToCoordinate").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
}
```

What I wanted is to make the input field not change color in any way at all. Which I simply can't make works. Any solution which needed CSS or javascript is fine. I want the form color to remain black at all time. Or is there a way to stop the form from doing the drop down suggestion thing when you click on the input form? Thanks

[I want the color to always be looking like the input form on the bottom, and not whitening up like the input form on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnTrc.png)

Comment: please provide and code working sample or image

Comment: @noob have I answered your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the image is in the post now. Click on the link with the explanation there. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Hover Effect

Remove this piece of code if you don't want the input color to change on hovering it:

```
.button:hover{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
```

#### Select Effect

Remove this piece of code if you don't want the input color to change on selecting it:

```
.button:focus{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); // Remove this line
        width: 300px;
}
```

,remove the `onclick="clickInput()"` from the Form and remove the function -

```
function clickInput() {
    document.getElementById("currentCoordinate").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
    document.getElementById("moveToCoordinate").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
}
```

#### Input Change Effect

Remove this piece of code if you don't want the input color to change when the data in the input box changes:

```
onchange="backgroundColor: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
```

#### Browser Effects

This is the default style added by the browser (Blue outline in most cases) to overcome this:

```
.button:focus{
        outline: none; // Add this line
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I forgot to say that I want the form to remain at the color rgba(0,0,0,0.7) all the time. When you type in the form, it changed from the color rgba(0,0,0,0.7) to white, and I am trying to stop that. I want the form to ALWAYS REMAIN AT COLOR rgba(0,0,0,0.7). Thanks for your help and sorry for not responding in time.